# Trouble with "viewWithTag"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

oldTag button is not changing back to white ??
What am I missing?

thx

```
-(void) myCharValue: (UIButton*)btn
{

    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; //current tag_button pressed

    UIButton *btnTemp;
    btnTemp = (UIButton*)[btnChar viewWithTag:oldTag];
    [btnTemp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // <--- oldTag button is not changing back to white ??

    oldTag = btn.tag;
}


//setup
for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {
            btnChar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
            [btnChar setFrame:CGRectMake(j*40+1, i*40+1, 38, 38)];
            [btnChar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [btnChar setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", k]  forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
            [btnChar setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnChar addTarget:self action:@selector(myCharValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnChar setTag:k];
            [svDisplay addSubview:btnChar];
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show how you are initially creating the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are subviews of `svDisplay`, not `btnChar`, so the line `btnTemp = (UIButton*)[btnChar viewWithTag:oldTag];` should be `btnTemp = (UIButton*)[svDisplay viewWithTag:oldTag];`.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that the default value of `tag` property is 0, so if you start your loop with 0, first button will technically not be tagged. Later when you request a `viewWithTag:` 0 from `svDisplay` (chech @jrtc27's answer), you will get a first view in that `[svDisplay subviews]` array.